# uml component diagram difference between assembly and interfaces with dependency

Tags: components, diagram, modeling

Can someone explain in what's the difference between elements marked in diagram?
I think it only depends on how many interfaces we want to connect. Am I right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EVln.png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not right and the diagram is syntactically incorrect.

Let me first explain the concepts and their meaning:
[image]

**Dependency** between components exist on the definition level (top part of the diagram). They can be drawn between the required and provided interface, between a component and interface or even between two components (no interfaces), depending on what we want to show.

**Assembly** is completelly different relationship and it does not make sense on the definition level (between components). It's because it is a special kind of link - a relationship established in run-time between two instances of a classifier (here - component, the lower diagram).

So, in summary we could say that a **dependency between two components on classifier level expresses a potential link or assembly between the corresponding instances in run-time.**

On your example there are several syntax errors (if you could compile it, it would give you this report :)):

- Assemblies "Item Code" and "Customer Details" cannot connect two components (**only their instances**)
- Dependency between Order and Account is in wrong direction (should go **from required to provided** **interface** with the same name)

Note: I must say that this diagram looks extremelly suspicious even semantically. You should probably reconsider it.

Comment: It was example which i found in web. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Ufff! No wonder that the current state of UML usage in the SW development world is so bad...

Comment: Great answer! Could you please share the references or the place where you got this information. I am searching for a good UML 2 source, but the web is full of incorrect usage :( Thank you!

Comment: For a practical example, see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124065.