# Is this diagram a valid UML component diagram?

Tags: architecture, components, uml, diagram, software-design

I am planning a new web application, therefore I want to create a component diagram which shows the architecture of the application.
Now I am actually not a specialist in UML and wanted to know if the diagram I made is correct for UML standardization.

I already used google a lot for some examples but none of these could really helped me with showing the database, orm and webbrowser in it.

So here is my actual result, would be great if I could receive some feedback for what is wrong and how it should be made correctly.

[image]

Comment: With a less formal diagram you would be much faster, and most likely even clearer. In the specific case 2 Lines of text would provide the same level of detail. (Yes that’s a UML rant, I think it’s social,acceptable to do that in 2019)

Comment: @eckes Maybe it's "acceptable" but still wrong, though. Those are the times.

Comment: What's the meaning of the dashed arrows? Wouldn't it be an aggregation relationship rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a component element, you may display *either* its internal structure *or* its packaged elements. It seems you are mixing these two up. If you want to display both, you have to use two separate compartments. Here is a figure 11.48 from the UML 2.5 specification:

[image: component]

I suggest you choose to show the internal structure. In that case, the elements inside the component symbol should be 'Parts', with a colon in front of the class name. The dashed arrows inside the component should be replaced by solid lines.

For more information, see [the answer to 'Component diagram dependency vs assembly'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124065/component-diagram-dependency-vs-assembly)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and hints.
I think this is exactly the answer I was looking for.

I just updatet my diagram hopefully it is correct now.
Could you please check it again. Thanks. :)

https://imgur.com/a/YShx85E

Comment: I still see the original diagram.

Comment: Did you check the link from my comment ?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Why do the classes inside `Order` have colons in front which make them look like instances?

Comment: In UML types are listed after the colon, you could also add instance names before the colon in an internal structure compartment (but not in Class diagrams as you can see in the packaged elements compartment, for whatever reasons)

Comment: @ThomasKilian: They are 'parts'. These are almost like instances, e.g. you could have several parts of type User (``Superuser : User``, ``Normaluser : User [*]``). I can't explain UML composite structures in one comment. Have a look at Figure 11.5 of the UML spec.

Comment: @MIstudent: Oh, sorry, now I see the new diagram.

Comment: The part inside Application is now a valid internal structure. But outside of Application, you should not apply the rules of internal structures. Just draw that exactly like in your original diagram. The connection between the socket (required interface, half circle) of Webbrowser and the Port should be a dependency, i.e. a dashed arrow pointing from the socket to the port. The connection between the ball (provided interface, full circle) of Database and the Port should be a dependency pointing from the Port to the ball.

Comment: Thanks again @www.admiraalit.nl I think it should be fine now.
Your were a big help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your diagram is fine (except for that filled arrow in the lower part). However, there's room for improvement.

[image]

You can show the required and provided interfaces on each port and delegate (see Edit below) functionality to the internal classes of the component. The above is very simplistic but it should make clear the use of `delegate` relations.

Also in a more coarse picture you could just leave away the inner part of `Application` and just show its ports/interfaces for an overview diagram:

[image]

**Edit**: One never stops learning. First, the arrow for required IF used to be the other way around in UML 2.1.1. But now (UML 2.5) they use just a straight line for delegation. No arrow nor keyword `delegate`.

Comment: Thank you for that great Feedback!